# Windows Forms DataGridView - adds too many rows

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

Troubleshooting an existing Windows Form application at work. When the Add Analyte button is pressed , 5 rows should appear and they do (sometimes, that's another bug). When you select another analyte and hit Add Analyte again, another 5 rows should appear. What happens is that another row for the previous analyte will appear and 6 rows for the second analyte.

[image: beforeAdd]
[image: afterAdd]

I have tried quite a few things - messing with For loop that adds the rows and making sure that the DataGridView.AllowUserToEdit is FALSE. I have run the debugger multiple times and this is the code right after number of rows goes from 5 to 12.

```vb
 Private Sub FillerUpToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FillerUpToolStripButton.Click

        Try
            Me.TblQCResultsTableAdapter.FillerUp(Me.DbCalcsDataSet.tblQCResults, New System.Nullable(Of Integer)(CType(QCIDToolStripTextBox.Text, Integer)))
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

The expected result is there should be 5 rows to start, then 10 rows total after this. There are other functions involved here but this is where the debugger showed me that the rowCount jumps from 5 to 12 when adding.

UPDATE

Here is some more code to help explain this question.
First here is the code for the AddAnalyte button click:

```vb
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        If Me.cmbAnalytes.SelectedIndices.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        If Me.dgvPatientReview.RowCount > 0 Then

            Me.Validate()
            Me.TblQCResultsBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TblQCResultsTableAdapter.Update(Me.DbCalcsDataSet.tblQCResults)

        End If

        For i = 0 To Me.cmbAnalytes.SelectedIndices.Count - 1
            AddFiveAnalytes(Me.cmbAnalytes.SelectedItems(i))
        Next

        Me.cmbAnalytes.ClearSelected()

        UpdateTable()

    End Sub
```

This might be where the issue is - since it is good the first time and breaks after adding more lines. I am not sure what it is actually doing in the if statement "If me.dgvPatientReview.RowCount > 0 then..."

The AddFiveAnalytes sub might also be the problem:

```vb
    Public Sub AddFiveAnalytes(ByVal test As String)

        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            For i = 0 To 5
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into tblQCResults (QCID, Analyte, [Within Tolerance], RevisedReport) VALUES (@QCID, @Analyte, 0, 0);"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QCID", intIncidence)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Analyte", test)

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Next
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Then the UpdateTable Sub could also be the issue:

```vb
   Public Sub UpdateTable()

        Dim Boo As Boolean = False

1:
        con.Close()
        con.Open()

        FillerUpToolStripButton.PerformClick()

        Dim intA As Integer = aRound(Me.dgvPatientReview.RowCount / 5, 0)

        If Not (Me.dgvPatientReview.RowCount / 5).ToString = intA.ToString Then
            If Boo = True Then
                MsgBox("There is an error in attempting to add 5 new lines. If you need more lines than are being shown, add 5 more. Any lines not used will be deleted when you save.")
                GoTo 2
            Else
                Boo = True
                GoTo 1
            End If
        End If
2:
        For i = 0 To Me.dgvPatientReview.RowCount - 1
            If Me.dgvPatientReview.Item(10, i).Value = True Then
                dgvPatientReview(11, i).Style.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
            Else
                dgvPatientReview(11, i).Style.BackColor = Color.Silver
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

I hope this information helps with answering this problem. VBA is definitely not my strong suit!

Comment: FillerUp looks like a custom Fill method.  You would have to document that for us.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the other functions so we may know where to help you from.

Comment: That rather stupidly-named `FillerUp` method is executing a query and populating the `Me.DbCalcsDataSet.tblQCResults` table with the result set. If that `DataTable` is bound to your grid then any rows in that result set will appear in the grid. If you are getting more rows than you expect then either there is something wrong with that query or there is something wrong with the data or your understanding of the query is incorrect. Whichever is the case, we can't help you because we don;t know what the query or the data is.